# How can i read a text file and assign multiple values to variables with multiple records?

Tags: oracle, function, variables, plsql, scripting

I have a query in Oracle 19c that grabs information from an inventory table about our databases.  it collects the database_name, hostname, pluggable_db_name, and service_name by joining several of out inventory tables.  This query works fine.  and its give us a result like this:

DB_NAME HOSTNAME    PDB_NAME   SERVICE_NAME

XXXDBTST XXXXADM02 XXXDBTST    XXXXXSTST  -- there are many rows like this

What i then need to do is to output these results into a text file, which we have working with spool.

From there, i need a function or procedure to read through the text file, assigning the string results to variables for later use.  What we want to do is take the host and  pdb name from the text file. So lets say VARIABLE 1 and VARIABLE3, and put it into the next part of our script to have a connection to the listed database.  This will happen for each different PDB. It will connect to the host from above(VARIABLE1), once connected, it will sqplus to the PDB from above(VARIABLE3).  After that it will query gv$services to give us the running services on that PDB.  From there it will compare the text file results from our inventory to the query results of what's actually present on the server.  If they match, great, if not then it should email us.  Basically we want to know if a database service is down or not with the correct PDB.

I assume we need a LOOP...or an ARRAY?  Right now first things first is trying to figure out how to assign the variables from the text file.  Given that there are multiple columns AND multiple rows, what is the best way to accomplish this?

We have the individual queries working, we just are hoping for some guidance on how to code this so it can be popped on a server with variables so that we don't hard code every database connection etc.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have enough info to construct a TNS string that would successfully connect, you can do this by simply reading from your spool file. Let's say your file looks like this:

```
DBTST ADM02 DBTST STST
```

I suggest adding a literal in your select to clearly mark the line as a record so you can cleanly read it without getting messed up with other junk from your spool:

```
DBRECORD DBTST ADM02 DBTST STST
```

Then in shell:

```
grep '^DBRECORD' spoolfile.txt | while read dummy db hostnm pdb svc
do
  # now make a connection using $db, $hostnm, $pdb, $svc vars
done
```

But be advised that in many environments making connections like this may not be so simple. Unless you have a `tnsnames` or `LDAP` directory set up that has every one of these databases registered uniquely by name, you may need to assemble the full string yourself, and depending on your organization's complexity that may require an abstracted host (SCAN or virtual) and also a port (if 1521 isn't always used) in order to construct reliable connection strings.

For this reason, in a very large complex corporate environment it is more maintainable to have crontab-scheduled clients running locally and connecting locally (without TNS/listeners) and pushing what they gather to a central location rather than trying to assemble and maintain up-to-date connection strings for everything and pulling from a central location. This method also enables you to remove account maintenance from the equation as you wouldn't need to have a predefined account everywhere in good status with a good password to monitor with.